# Fullcalendar not rendering on first load - SFDC

Tags: salesforce, fullcalendar

1. Fullcalendar is not getting loaded on the first load. After a refresh store? it is working fine

I have included below library in the same order.

```
    jquery.min.js - v3.3.1
    moment.min.js 
    fullcalendar.min.js - 3.9.0
    fullcalendar.min.css - 3.9.0
```

Comment: Hello, please include your initialization function of the calendar. Also, it is always nice to try to post your minimal working code (please read this document: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, use DevTools console in Chrome or Firefox (or similar in other browsers) and report what kind of JavaScript error you receive in Console on the first run. You can try to fix this usually with: $(document).ready(function() {$('#calendar').fullCalendar({})});

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not get any error on first load. I also used above code snippet i.e $('#calendar').fullCalendar({})}. It says fullCalendar is not a function.

Comment: Please, post some code as it is impossible to help you. Also, you have /demos/ folder in the library, try to use them first, see if those work on your system and analyse the structure of the source html.

Comment: From the documentation: "If you are using <script> tags and browser globals, you must ensure the original non-plugin moment.js dist file from the Moment site is included on your page first.". Move your moment.js script on top over jquery and try if that solves your issue. Also, it is included first in the demos.

Comment: Here is code snippet. I have two lightning components. 
Outer component Library included -  <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', $Resource.JVM_AnyEventCal + '/jquery.min.js', $Resource.JVM_AnyEventCal + 
                           '/moment.min.js',  $Resource.JVM_AnyEventCal + '/fullcalendar.min.js')}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />   

Inner component library - <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.JVM_AnyEventCal + '/fullcalendar.min.css'}"/>

Comment: ControllerJs - 
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
        helper.getEvents(component, event);
    }
getEvents method pulls the value of field.

Comment: Please, try to move moment.js on top of jquery in your scripts loading sequence. Also, try this in your initialization code: $(window).load(function() {$('#calendar').fullcalendar('render');}

Comment: Also, you should include .css files before .js scripts.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to notice in full calendar behavior, the calendar gets loaded first time but if we go to different tab and come back to the same tab - it does not get loaded until refreshing the window.